# How can I change the label text in form "a" when a button is pressed in form "b" .net C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I was wondering if someone could help?

The goal of DataEntryForm  is to return a string to form1.

1. The DataEntryForm is created and opened when btnOpen is pressed which is located on form1.
2. The value in the text box in DataEntryForm should be returned to form1 when btnOK is pressed.

I've tried using event handlers so far but not had any luck. Any suggestions?

[image: DataEntryForm]

[image: form1]

Comment: You need to use an instance of the form class to pass data.  See my two form project at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: @jdweng I've had a look at the post - the button that is pressed that runs GetData() I think is on the form where the data is returned to. Is that true? It's just I'd like the button that would start it to be on the data entry form

Comment: My code opens a form and then returns without closing by capturing the close event.  Normally a form returns and gets disposed.  So you can pass info to a 2nd form by either including in the constructor or keeping the form open and then reading the values from the instance of the form.

Answer (score 1):

Add a public property InputValue to the DataEntryForm. When user clicks the button on the form assign the property and close the DataEntryForm:

```
this.InputValue = textbox.Text;
```

Opening and reading the value:

```
using (var formDE = new DataEntryForm()) 
{ 
    if (formDE.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
    { 
        // access the returned value
        string value = formDE.InputValue
    } 
},
```

Comment: `using (var formDE = new DataEntryForm()) { if (formDE.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) { ... } }`, so you can remove all the `Dispose()` stuff.

Answer (score 1):

My favorite way to do this is to encapsulate the logic in a static method of the form. Static methods have access to the form's private members so you don't have to worry about exposing anything in public properties.

```
class DataEntryForm : Form
{
    /* The rest of your class goes here */

    public static string Execute()
    {
        using (var form = new DataEntryForm())
        {
            var result = form.ShowDialog();
            return (result == DialogResult.OK) ? form.MyTextBox.Text : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in form1, all you have to do is this:

```
var enteredText = DataEntryForm.Execute();
```